# Custom validation in Meteor.loginWithPassword

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have created a custom login page and used the Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, [callback]) function to login to the app. Js file is like this:

```
  Template.login.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var emailVar = event.target.loginEmail.value;
        var passwordVar = event.target.loginPassword.value;
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar, passwordVar, function(error) {
            if (error) {

                Bert.alert(error.reason, 'danger', 'growl-top-right');
            } else {
                Router.go('/dashboard');
            }
        });
    }
})
```

And my HTML file is like this:

```
<template name="login">

          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
            <input type="email" name="loginEmail" class="form-control" placeholder= {{getLanguageValue "profile_email"}}>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
            <input type="password" name="loginPassword" class="form-control" placeholder= {{getLanguageValue "myprofile_password"}}>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-default"> Submit</button>
```

I need another validation in error.reason for checking blocked users. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of checking if a user is blocked is on the server. If he's blocked he shouldn't login at all.

Once `loginWithPassword` is called in the client, `validateLoginAttempt` is called on the server. This way you can perform checks on the server and abort login by throwing an error or continue login by returning true.

This is how I would do it:

> On the client (login.js)

```
Template.login.events({
  'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var emailVar = event.target.loginEmail.value;
    var passwordVar = event.target.loginPassword.value;
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar, passwordVar, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        if (error.reason === 'Your account is blocked') {
          Bert.alert("This user is blocked by admin and can not login", 'danger', 'growl-top-right');
        } else {
          Bert.alert(error.reason, 'danger', 'growl-top-right');
        }
      } else {
        Router.go('/dashboard');
      }
    });
  },
});
```

> On the server (server.js)

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt((info) => {
  const user = info && info.user;

  if (user && user.profile && user.profile.isBlocked == 1) {
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Your account is blocked');
  }

  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a helper function and check is user blocked before calling `loginWithPassword` method.

Something like this:

```
isBlocked = function(id) {
   user = Meteor.users().findOne(id);

   if user && user.profile && user.profile.isBlocked && user.profile.isBlocked == 1;
}
```

Or you can call this method in `loginWithPassword` callback and if user is blocked call logout function.

Comment: How can I call this helper in Meteor.loginWithPassword part .I write this :  `else if (isBlocked(emailVar)) {
                     console.log('here in block');
                     Bert.alert("This user is blocked by admin and can not login", 'danger', 'growl-top-right');
                }` But I get this error : Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login': ReferenceError: isBlocked is not defined

Comment: bind the `isBLocked` into callback function.

Comment: I dont know how t call a helper inside submit event .is it correct like this? this.isBlocked(emailVar)

Comment: Where you have defined the `isBlocked` function? just create a `helpers.js` in `lib` folder and define the function there.

Answer (score 0):

I just change else part like this and It works:

```
  'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var emailVar = event.target.loginEmail.value;
        var passwordVar = event.target.loginPassword.value;

        Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar, passwordVar, function(error) {
          //console.log('here');
            if (error) {
                Bert.alert(error.reason, 'danger', 'growl-top-right');
            }
             else {
                  var user= Meteor.users.findOne({ "emails.0.address": emailVar })

                  if (user && user.profile && user.profile.isBlock && user.profile.isBlock == 1){
                    Bert.alert("This user is blocked by admin and can not login", 'danger', 'growl-top-right');
                  }
                  else {
                     Router.go('/dashboard');
                  }
            }
        });
    },
```

But I like to create a function named isBlocked and call this function in every Js file .like a global function.

this should be the function :

```
isBlocked = function(id) {
 user = Meteor.users().findOne(id);

 if user && user.profile && user.profile.isBlocked && user.profile.isBlocked == 1;
}
```

I don't know where should I define this function in meteor and how can I call it in submit event.